# Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I am developing the ASP.NET Core Application using the latest .NET Core 3.1.1 and `System.Text.Json` which was previously using the `Newtonsoft.Json`. As recommended in the Microsoft [Migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to)
I have done the changes. Also, as most of my enums need to be serialized as String I have configured my Startup.cs `ConfigureServices` to use the `JsonStringEnumConverter` globally.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // lines omitted for brevity

    services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                    });
}
```

But recently, after the release we realized that only a few enums are given out as numerals in json through our API. As these APIs are consumed externally, changing the numerals to strings might be a costly stuff.

So, is there a way to ignore the universal for some enum properties like the decoration with the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=netcore-3.1) is actually a subclass of [`JsonConverterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterfactory?view=netcore-3.1).  It manufactures a specific [`JsonConverterEnum`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/JsonConverterEnum.cs) for each concrete `enum` type encountered during serialization that, in turn, serializes that specific `enum` type as a string.

If you don't want some specific `enum` **type** to be serialized as a string, you can use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and create your own converter factory that decorates a `JsonStringEnumConverter` but prevents that `enum` type from being converted as follows:

```
public class OptOutJsonConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactoryDecorator
{
    readonly HashSet<Type> optOutTypes;

    public OptOutJsonConverterFactory(JsonConverterFactory innerFactory, params Type [] optOutTypes) : base(innerFactory) => this.optOutTypes = optOutTypes.ToHashSet();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => base.CanConvert(typeToConvert) && !optOutTypes.Contains(typeToConvert);
}

public class JsonConverterFactoryDecorator : JsonConverterFactory
{
    readonly JsonConverterFactory innerFactory;

    public JsonConverterFactoryDecorator(JsonConverterFactory innerFactory)
    {
        if (innerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerFactory));
        this.innerFactory = innerFactory;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => innerFactory.CanConvert(typeToConvert);

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => innerFactory.CreateConverter(typeToConvert, options);
}
```

Then use it in options as follows:

```
options.Converters.Add(new OptOutJsonConverterFactory(new JsonStringEnumConverter(), 
                                                      // Add here all enum types to serialize as integers:
                                                      typeof(SomeEnumNotToSerializeAsAString)
                                                      //, ...
                                                     ));
```

Notes:

- If maintaining a list of enum types to serialize as integers is inconvenient, you could mark the enum types to be serialized as integers with some custom [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute), then exclude types marked with that attribute from within `CanConvert(CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)`.
- The decorator pattern is required because `JsonStringEnumConverter` is sealed.

Mockup fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XtMsKU).

Alternatively, if you don't want some specific `enum` **property** to be serialized as a string, you can apply a converter to the property using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=netcore-3.1) that ignores the incoming `JsonSerializerOptions` and generates a default serialization instead:

```
/// <summary>
/// Apply this converter to a property to force the property to be serialized with default options.  
/// This converter can ONLY be applied to a property; setting it in options or on a type may cause a stack overflow exception!
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">the property's declared return type</typeparam>
public class SerializePropertyAsDefaultConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader); // Ignore the incoming options!
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value); // Ignore the incoming options!
    } 
}
```

And apply it to your model as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    public StringEnum StringEnum { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(SerializePropertyAsDefaultConverter<SomeEnumNotToSerializeAsAString>))]
    public SomeEnumNotToSerializeAsAString SomeEnumNotToSerializeAsAString { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- This solution takes advantage of the [documented precedence for converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#converter-registration-precedence):

  > 1. `[JsonConverter]` applied to a property.
  > 2. A converter added to the Converters collection.
  > 3. `[JsonConverter]` applied to a custom value type or POCO.

Mockup fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p8e9Ib).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation @dbc.