# Is there an alternative to StringEnumConverter in .Net Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, asp.net-core-3.0, system.text.json

In .net core prior to version 3 there when `Newtonsof.Json` was used there was a possibility to inherit from `StringEnumConverter` to add additional validation or a custom error message for the process of binding a string to enum.

I cannot find it's counterpart in .Net Core 3. There is a `JsonStringEnumConverter` but it is sealed. It seems the only option is to write the whole converter myself and I'd like to avoid that.

P.S. I know it is possible to fall back to `Newtonsoft.Json` and use it as before, but I want to use the new Microsoft implementation.

Comment: You can still use Json.net in .NET Core 3. It's just that .NET Core 3 introduced its own JSON library, `System.Text.Json`. This is not Json.net, and doesn't provide all of the same capabilities.

Comment: Yes, I know, forgot to mention that I'd rather use the new json library :)

Comment: Cool, it sounded like you were confused that `StringEnumConverter` had gone in .NET Core 3 specifically (i.e. in Json.net on .NET Core 3), and not in `System.Text.Json`

Comment: there is often a lot of confusion around that if one does not read changelog from microsoft :) Fortunately they are doing a way better job now with these than before

Comment: You could follow the decorator pattern and create your own `JsonConverterFactory` for enums that delegates to `JsonStringEnumConverter` for the default case but manufactures a specific converter for some override case.  See e.g. [Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59828937/3744182).

Comment: Or if `JsonStringEnumConverter` is too limiting (no support for custom names) you could use a third party converter like the one from [`Macross.Json.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions/).  See e.g. [System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59059989/3744182).