# How to ignore null properties when serializing to JSON in middleware?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, .net-core

In `ASP.NET Core Web API` I want to ignore null properties, when returning the following DTO class (I'm using `System.Text.Json;`, not `Newtonsoft.Json`). I want to do it in middleware (in Startup class), not in Controller. Here's the C# class:

```
public class VehicleOutput
{
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public Truck Truck { get; set; }
}
```

This is `JSON` I'd like to return (I don't want to show `"car": null` if `Car` in fact is null, and same for `Truck`):

```
[
    {
        "vehicleId": 1,
        "owner": "ABS",
        "car": 
        {
            "carId": 123,
            "model": "Foo"
        }
    },
    {
        "vehicleId": 2,
        "owner": "ABS",
        "truck": 
        {
            "truckId": 123,
            "model": "Bar"
        }
    }
]
```

I was able to achive that by doing this in the `Controller`. It works!:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetVehicles()
    {
        var vehiclesOutput = await _vehicleService.GetVehicles();

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            IgnoreNullValues = true,
            WriteIndented = true
        };

        return Ok(JsonSerializer.Serialize(vehiclesOutput, options));
    }
```

But I don't want to repeat this code every time I return `VehicleOutput` class. So I want to do it in middleware. This is what I got:

```
        services.AddControllers()
           .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
           {
               opt.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
           });
```

It works! It ignores null properties in JSON, but it does it for every object I'm returning in the API. I want to add this option ONLY for specific classes (like `VehicleOutput`). How can you do that in `Startup` class?

**Bear in mind...** I'm not using `Newtonsoft.Json`. I'm using `System.Text.Json;` and I want to stick with it (if possible)

Comment: _“I want to add this option ONLY for specific classes”_ – As far as I am aware, System.Text.Json does not offer you this level of control (yet). If you require this, you will have to use a different serializer.

Comment: @poke how to use different serializer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828937/exclude-an-enum-property-of-a-model-from-using-the-jsonstringenumconverter-which)