# How to ignore global JsonStringEnumConverter for specific enum type

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, system.text.json

Is there a way to annotate a POCO so that the JsonStringEnumConverter is ignored?
I currently have this configured in my Startup class:

```
mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));
    // ... other options ...
});
```

But then I have an enum which I want to be serialized with the numberic value and not the string value

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(... what goes here ...)]
public enum TypeIdentifier
{
    value1,
    value2
}
```

expected serialisation:

```
{
    "myProperty":1
}
```

Comment: See [Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832092/3744182). Using `OptOutJsonConverterFactory` from that answer in your options should do what you need.  Let me know if that answers your question.  Or, do you require to apply the converter directly to `TypeIdentifier` rather than in options?

Comment: Also, you can't supersede a converter added to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` with a converter applied to a type, because the order of precedence of converters in `System.Text.Json` is [*Attribute on property / Converters collection / Attribute on type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#converter-registration-precedence).  This differs from Json.NET where the type converters supersede runtime converters.

Comment: Ideally I need to specify it on the TypeIdentifier so that any consumer of the type does not need to change their settings.

Comment: My main problem is...
What converter do I specify to force the numerical serialization instead of the global string serialization?

Comment: *Ideally I need to specify it on the TypeIdentifier* - sadly that seems not to be possible as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#converter-registration-precedence).  *What converter do I specify to force the numerical serialization* -- you need **no converter at all** to do this, it is the default behavior.  You need to disable `JsonStringEnumConverter` for your specific enum, which `OptOutJsonConverterFactory` allows you to do.