# Jsonconverter type to revert to default converter on a field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, system.text.json

I'm using `System.Text.Json` in my ASP.NET Core C# solution and by default, I have the JSON string enum converter enabled. However, on a handful of fields, I'd like to return my enums as the underlying `byte`/`int` type without having to

1. set the type to a byte/int (I want to retain the fact it's an enum)  or;
2. removing the JSON string enum converter from everything.

Is there a way of using `[JsonConverter(type)]` on a specific field to force the enum to output as the byte/int instead of the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59828937/3744182).  Agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom converter, for example:

```
public class JsonIntEnumConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : Enum
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Enum test = (Enum)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString());
        writer.WriteNumberValue(Convert.ToInt32(test));
    }
}
```

Now in you class, any properties you want to keep as `int`, just add the `JsonConverter` attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonIntEnumConverter<MyEnum>))]
public MyEnum SomeValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks! This and the link to the duplicate are the perfect solution for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would not dismiss the `int` solution.

It's very simple and very clear to consumers - no surprise that enum comes as number.

```
public enum Number { Zero, One, Two, Three };
public class X
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Number N { get; set; }

    public int NVal => (int)N;

    public Number N2 { get; set; }        
}
```

Then with

```
var o = new X { N = Number.One, N2 = Number.Two };

var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
};

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(o, serializeOptions));
```

the result is:

```
{
  "NVal": 1,
  "N2": "Two"
}
```