# System.Text.Json: How to serialize a individual enum as number when the json configuration has a general JsonStringEnumConverter

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, enums, system.text.json

System.Text.Json default to number the **enum** serialization. In my case I need the string for that in the Startup.cs I add a converter to get all the **enum** serializing to string as is show here.

```
 .AddJsonOptions(
           c =>
           {
             c.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
          }
        );
```

but I have a particular **enum** that I need to serialize to number.

```
public enum fareStatus
{
    None = 0,
    Club = 1,
    NoClub = 2
}
```

In this case I want to get 0,1,2 and not the string,

is that possible in this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: If I read this correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#converter-registration-precedence Then a Converter applied to a Property of that Enum Type should take precedence over the Converter in the list. But don't take my word for it. Didn't try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try to use other converter but does not work for me, is there a converter to back the serialization to its default value? if exists that should be a nice solution. if not I suppose that I need to create a custom converter

Comment: Can you post the object you try to serialize?

Comment: Use `new OptOutJsonConverterFactory(new JsonStringEnumConverter(), typeof(fareStatus))` where `OptOutJsonConverterFactory` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832092/3744182) to [Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59828937/3744182).

Comment: If you don't use the serialization options, the default is the numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get just number from enum try this

```
    var item = new Item { Status = fareStatus.NoClub };
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    var json= JsonSerializer.Serialize(item,options);
```

json

```
{"Status":2}
```

and try this code

```
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    var json= JsonSerializer.Serialize(item,options);

    item=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Item>(json,options);
```

json

```
{"Status":"NoClub"}
```

class

```
public class Item
{
    public fareStatus Status {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This worked for what I wanted to do, which was the complete opposite of what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: @ejcortes There are both cases here. OP can select any he wants.