# How to serialize a simple Enum as Integer instead of String By Default in .NET 6

Tags: json, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json, refit

I am using Refit Client to call APIs in .NET and here it is my refit settings

```
var refitSettings = new RefitSettings(
                         new SystemTextJsonContentSerializer(
                             new JsonSerializerOptions()
                             {
                                 PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                                 PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                                 Converters = {
                                         new JsonStringEnumMemberConverter(),
                                         new ObjectToInferredTypesConverter()
                                 }
                             })
                         );
```

I am configuring it like this

```
 services.AddRefitClient<ISomeRefitApi>(refitSettings);
```

This is my Enum

```
public enum GenderType
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    Other = 3
}
```

But it is being serialized as Male/Female/Other with above options I want it to be 1/2/3

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: enum Sides {
    Left, Right, Top, Bottom
}
Sides side = Sides.Bottom;

object val = Convert.ChangeType(side, side.GetTypeCode());
Console.WriteLine(val); from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: I'd try GenderType zz = GenderType.Male; int x = (int) zz;

Comment: `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` is **probably** what is serializing all enums as strings.  (I say "probably" because it's not a system type but rather it's some custom type, so I don't know exactly what it does -- unless you copied it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061296) in which case it will definitely serialize your enum as a string.)  If you don't want that, then just don't use it.

Comment: If you want to continue to use `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` for every enum type other than `GenderType`, you could use `OptOutJsonConverterFactory` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832092/3744182) to [Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59828937/3744182) like so: `new OptOutJsonConverterFactory(new JsonStringEnumMemberConverter(), typeof(GenderType))`.  Does that answer your question?