# Enum string serialization not working as expected in .net 6.0

Tags: serialization, json.net, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I have a production api returning the below json:

```json
[
  {
    "StartUtc": "2023-09-02T13:52:00Z",
    "EndUtc": "2023-09-02T15:19:00Z",
    "isCustomerInStore": false,
    "productLead": {
      "id": 1,
      "leadType": "PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER",
      "leadStatus": "SOLD_DELIVERED",
      "leadStatusType": "SOLD",
      "leadSourceId": 11,
      "leadSourceName": "Previous  Customer"
    },
    "customer": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "salesRepresentative": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Sales",
        "lastName": "Guy1",
        "assignedUserType": "SALES_REPRESENTATIVE"
      }
    },
    "product": {
      "year": 2023,
      "make": "Google",
      "model": "Pixel",
      "stockNumber": "ABCD1234"
    }
  }
]
```

After the serialization of the above json, my api returns the below.

```json
[
  {
    "StartUtc": "2023-09-02T13:52:00Z",
    "EndUtc": "2023-09-02T15:19:00Z",
    "isCustomerInStore": false,
    "productLead": {
      "id": 1,
      "leadType": "previouS_CUSTOMER",
      "leadStatus": "solD_DELIVERED",
      "leadStatusType": "sold",
      "leadSourceId": 11,
      "leadSourceName": "Previous  Customer"
    },
    "customer": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "salesRepresentative": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Sales",
        "lastName": "Guy1",
        "assignedUserType": "saleS_REPRESENTATIVE"
      }
    },
    "product": {
      "year": 2023,
      "make": "Google",
      "model": "Pixel",
      "stockNumber": "ABCD1234"
    }
  }
]
```

The `leadType`, `leadStatus`, `leadStatusType` & `assignedUserType` are enum fields having attributes `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`. Also, all the enums have the attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]`. But they are returning with first few characters serialized to lower characters? Any ideas why?

Comment: You are mixing converters from different serializers.  [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter) is from System.Text.Json while [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) is from Newtonsoft.Json.  That's likely to produce unexpected behaviors.  Which serializer are you actually using?  The value `"previouS_CUSTOMER"` looks **camel cased** so somewhere you must be applying a camel casing enum converter.

Comment: Also, might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing simplified versions of your enums and classes and your API startup configuration that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @dbc: I had the problem before when I had these converters added. I thought adding this would cause the problem to go away. It didn't.


I will try share the minimal reproducible example. But the issue is happening when I submit a request to the api using Postman. When I debug, I do see the enum is mapped correctly from my production api to my new api

Comment: It's happening because somewhere on the server side you are configuring a JSON converter for your enums that serializes in camel case.  In order to help you resolve the problem we need to know what serializer you are using and how you configured it.  The fact that you are invoking the server with Postman should not matter.

Comment: You were right!

I had the below in the pipeline file `Program.cs`
`options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase))`

I removed `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` constructor argument and it worked just fine.

Comment: @dbc: Can you add it as an answer? I will accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"previouS_CUSTOMER"` is the **camel case** serialization of `PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER` generated by System.Text.Json.  Somewhere in your startup method you must be constructing a [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-serialization-jsonstringenumconverter-ctor(system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-system-boolean)) using [`JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.camelcase), e.g. in [`Program.cs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters)

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(
            new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)); // HERE
    });
```

To prevent this, you have a few options:

**Firstly**, if you never want camel case serialization of enums, just don't use `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` with `JsonStringEnumConverter`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(
            new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
```

You can still use camel case for your property names.

**Secondly**, if you want camel case serialization of enums for most enums but not your `LeadType` enum, use `OptOutJsonConverterFactory` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832092/3744182) to *[Exclude an enum property of a Model from using the JsonStringEnumConverter which is globally set at the Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59828937/3744182)* to disable its use for `LeadType`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(
            new OptOutJsonConverterFactory(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase),
                                           typeof(LeadType)));
        // Add a non-camel-case fallback converter for the opted out enum types:
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HBIK8Y).

**Finally**, if you don't want camel case enum serialization for the `LeadType` **property**, apply [`[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=net-6.0) to the property like so:

```
public class ProductLead
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(
        typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public LeadType LeadType { get; set; }
    
    // Other properties omitted
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jbJ9zt).

Notes:

1. As explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#converter-registration-precedence), converters are chosen with the following precedence:

   > - `[JsonConverter]` applied to a property.
   > - A converter added to the `Converters` collection.
   > - `[JsonConverter]` applied to a custom value type or POCO.

   As you can see, converters added to options supersede converters applied to types (but not properties).  This is why applying `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` to your enum types did not solve the problem.
2. You wrote that you applied

   ```
   [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
   ```

   To each property type, but [`StringEnumConverter` is from Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm), a completely different serializer.  System.Text.Json has an attribute [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute) with the same name as Newtonsoft's [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) so it's easy to get them confused.  When using both serializers, I recommend using the fully qualified name for metadata attributes.